# I run a full node. Is there a desktop client to connect to this full node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, nodes, mac, full-node

I run a full node on my Raspberry Pi at home. I want a desktop wallet that uses this full node. Not interested in using remote-x or xpra or setting up an electrum server.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few android wallets that can. For desktop i guess you could run a bitcoin-qt in pruning and blockonly mode to make it as lightweight as possible. Make a whitelisted connection to your full node (possibly over Tor if you're not at home).

Maybe the Neutrino medium weight client (no experience though).

Answer (score 0):

armory or msigna could probably connect to it.